# Point light range in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, range, point, lighting

I using Python with OpenGL, but the lighting doesn't work correctly. There is one point light:

```
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, (-26.5, -17.0, 17.0, 1.0))
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, 0.0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 50.0)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 50.0)
```

I see nothing but the color of the ambient lighting. This is likely because I didn't set the range of the light, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging back into legacy OpenGL documentation, most of your parameters look kind of suspect:

- `GL_SPOT_DIRECTION` is a vector. You pass a single float value, but need to pass a vector with 3 float values instead. This is the direction the light source is pointing.
- `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` should be between 0.0 and 90.0. The value 180.0 you are using disables the spotlight. Try something like 45.0 instead.
- `GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION` divides the intensity of the light be the give value. Since you specify 50.0, your light intensity would be only 2% of the full value, which will make the effect close to unnoticeable. Try a much smaller value, for example just leaving it at 1.0.

Check out the Lighting chapter in the freely available online version of the Red Book for diagrams and more detailed explanations of these parameters: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now the lights work. One last question: if I make a positional light using just glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)) I get a white light. How can I make that light blue? The link you gave was very good, but didn't say anything about that.

Comment: The light sources have `G_AMBIENT`, `GL_DIFFUSE`, and `GL_SPECULAR` parameters that allow you to set light colors. For example, `glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)` should make the diffuse part of your light source blue.